# How do you drop only 1 table using Schema Builder & Migration in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, schema, laravel-6

Let's say I have 4 tables in my database, and I want to only drop this table using a migration.

**2019_11_27_093224_create_objects_table.php***\

```php
class CreateObjectsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('objects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_object', 'KO0');
            $table->string('nama_layanan');
            $table->string('tipe_object');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('objects');
    }
}
```

Can I drop this table alone or do I need to wipe out all of my tables in my database?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do that just use phpmyadmin and drop the table manually. Of course if the migration is still there when you run the migration again the table will be created again.

If you do not want to re-create/migrate the table, just remove in under /database/migrations

Comment: Yes I know that, but I kinda want to just work in migration for my database to get used to it :D

Answer (score 0):

That is very easy. You just create a new migration to turn around above migration

```
php artisan make:migration drop_objects_table.

class DropObjectsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('objects');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::create('objects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_object', 'KO0');
            $table->string('nama_layanan');
            $table->string('tipe_object');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

Laravel supports create a migrations table in your database, in this table  has id, migration_name, step of migrating when you run command. You can rollback 1 or many step in migrations table. You can read in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#rolling-back-migrations)

Comment: cool! it works, but, can I delete all of 'objects' migration file in migration folder because I don't need it anymore? @luongps

Comment: yes absolutely, you can delete all of them if you do not need them in your source, but you need to run migrate first to remove the table in your database and after this delete them. @agastyarimbawa

Comment: you are welcome :D nice because it is helpful for you.